# How to validate with 2 buttons in same form in ASP. NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form with 2 buttons, and they're in same action, but when `Confirm` button is pressed, it doesn't need to validate, just press and go to the action, but when `Reject` button is pressed, then Textarea `Comment` must be filled in.

This is my view:

```
@if (Model.signingFlowViewModel.signingFlows.Count(s => s.SigningUser == User.Identity.Name && s.Status == "1") > 0)
{
   using (Html.BeginForm("OvertimeSigningAsync", "Signing", FormMethod.Post,
      new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');" }))
   {
<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit"
                   name="Sign" value="Confirm"
                   class="form-control btn btn-primary"
                   style="margin-bottom: 5px" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit"
                   name="Sign" value="Reject"
                   class="form-control btn btn-danger"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DocNo, new { @class = "hidden" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlowNo, new { @class = "hidden" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Plant, new { @class = "hidden" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @required  = "required" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewDocNo, new { @class = "hidden" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   }
}
```

And this is Action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OvertimeSigningAsync([Bind(Include = "Plant,FlowNo,DocNo,Comment,NewDocNo")] 
OvertimeSigningViewModel overtimeSigningViewModel, string Sign)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (ModelState.IsValid && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Sign))
    {
        result = eISRepository.EditPurchaseRequest(
                    overtimeSigningViewModel.Plant,
                    overtimeSigningViewModel.FlowNo,
                    overtimeSigningViewModel.DocNo,
                    User.Identity.Name, Sign,
                    overtimeSigningViewModel.Comment, 
                    overtimeSigningViewModel.NewDocNo);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I validate the textarea when button `Reject` is pressed.
I'm just newbie in MVC, so please help. Thanks so much

Comment: you can validate use jquery

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want to use validation of MVC

Answer (score 0):

I have found it, just add attribute `formnovalidate` on button Confirm, it is OK

```
<input type="submit" name="Sign" value="Confirm" class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 5px" formnovalidate/>
```